# Dataset of unstructured road image

Tags: images, photographs

I search for the dataset of images of unstructured roads (images of snowy/dirt/rainy/broken roads).

Currently, I've collected ~130 images manually.
If someone can share or point out to the public dataset of images of unstructured roads, I'd really be thankful for that. :)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]